# Choose from Illustrator PDF presets

Tags: pdf, applescript, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to find a way of creating a dialogue that lists the user's Adobe illustrator PDF presets to choose from.

This would then be set to save the specified file to a PDF. I've got the script all sorted and working for exporting a file(s) with a specified preset, but would like to be able to choose which PDF preset is used.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
on open (Itemlist)
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    set pdfPresets to PDF presets
end tell
set choosePDF to choose from list pdfPresets with prompt "Choose PDF preset:"
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with thisItem in Itemlist
        tell application "Finder" to set this_folder to (the POSIX path of thisItem)
        tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to open thisItem
        tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to save current document in this_folder as pdf with options {class:PDF save options, PDF preset:choosePDF}
        tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to close current document
    end repeat
    tell application "Finder" to activate
end tell
end open
```

Figured it out! Posted for anyone asking the same in the future.